# setAlarmClock not exact in android marshmallow

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I use `setAlarmClock` method of `Alarmmanager` for do alarm clock application.
When I set alarm clock from 6.00 AM and alarm in 6.01 AM . It delay and not exact.

Code when `setAlarmClock`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
intent.putExtra(AppConstant.REMINDER, note.convertToString());
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
        note.getId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    alarmManager.setAlarmClock(new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(getTargetTime().getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent),pendingIntent);
}
```

Code when setCalander for alarm

```
  private Calendar getTargetTime() {
    Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();
    calSet.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, sDay);
    calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, sHour);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, sMinute);
    calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    return calSet;
}
```

Ok, I implement from this project https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DirectBoot.

This project use setAlarmClock for alarm when it's time.

update: I change setAlarmClock to setExact

This code:

```
 alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, getTargetTime().getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

It doesn't work for me but It delay same setAlarmClock.

Current Time in millisecond: 1473318858628
I change to default format by use http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators/#.V9EPXfmLRD8

Thu Sep 08 2016 14:14:18 GMT+0700

Set Alarm Time in millisecond:1473318960000

Thu Sep 08 2016 14:16:00 GMT+0700

And now It's 14:16:00 , It doesn't alarm.

It's alarm on 14.20:00 , so delay about 4 minutes. ( Time in millisecond = 1473319200207)

Thank

Comment: is this on a device or on an emulator? If its a device, then try this same code on an emulator. It may potentially be a problem with the device. Some devices actually cause issues with alarms. Also another thing you can try is try the sample project and see if the schedule is correct (if applicable)

Comment: Ok Thankyou , I use device wiko ufeed ( android marshmallow) , I will try emulator . Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 2):

You should read the documentation. This is by design as according to the documentation with the excerpt:

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.

### Ref

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Ok , thankyou . Show that setalarmclock is inexact ?. And use setWindow instead of setalarmclock but I see other alarmclock application use setAlarmclock because I see alarm image in right of status bar on mobile when I set alarmclock.

Comment: I use setWindow and setExact , it doesn't work for me.

Comment: You're not supposed to use both, its either or. Also "Doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything. What have you validated that its actually scheduled correctly?

Comment: I validated by print getTimeInMilli and covert to real time. It is delay from time that I set. Do you have another way? Thankyou very much

Comment: Ok , I update my post when I use setExact. Sorry for the inconvenience. And thankyou for help me.

Answer (score -1):

Use setAlarmClock instead of setExact if you are using it in alarm clock.

In your code:

```
alarmManager.setAlarmClock(new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(getTargetTime().getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent),pendingIntent);
```

maybe something is wrong with your getTargetTime(). Try manually setting time by 1 less minute by adding

```
alarmManager.setAlarmClock(new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(getTargetTime().getTimeInMillis()-60*1000,pendingIntent),pendingIntent);
```